# Support for Postgres broken in HHVM 3.6.0

Tags: postgresql, hhvm

I keep getting

```
Uncaught exception: Could not open extension /etc/hhvm/extensions/pgsql.so: /etc/hhvm/extensions/pgsql.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4HPHP13PDOConnection5sweepEv
```

When I try to start up HHVM.  It was working prior to a HHVM which I applied (yesterday) as part of the standard upgrade process.

Rebuilding the pgsql.so fails with the bulk of the problem seeming to rest in the file

```
hhvm-pgsql-master/pdo_pgsql_statement.cpp
```

Is there a patch for this, or how would I be able to revert to a version of HHVM that does support this postgres extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use a package here:

http://dl.hhvm.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/hhvm/

I reverted back to hhvm_3.5.1~trusty_amd64.deb (please use the one appropriate for your server) with wget and dpkg.

I'm using percona MySQL and hhvm 3.6.0 took down my wordpress site with database errors.

Hopefully, these problems get fixed. I would love to be able to get future updates for hhvm as they come.

Comment: here's the 3.6.0 fix for mysql https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/4987#issuecomment-78046640

Comment: Not exactly a "fix". More like a Band-Aid for incompatibility issues.